# How can i implement asp.net with existing Database using database First in asp.net mvc, i'm using mac os

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, ado.net

In mysql server, i create a database with tow tables after i create a new project asp.net mvc in visual studio but i don't find how to implement asp.net with existing Database using database First in asp.net mvc, i'm using mac os.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your existing database for your project then you can easily do it with Database First approach.
Please follow this official [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/) for detailed explanation of "Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Database First Using MVC 5".

Comment: It is for windows os, i'm using mac os.